# Trouble with json convert

Tags: python-requests

Im just a beginner with python but have a plan to working hard to be expert soon:)

I tried to convert to json nad have error:

> Response not in valid JSON format

and

> class 'requests.models.Response'>

```
url="https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Strona_g%C5%82%C3%B3wna"

    try:

response = requests.get(url)

if not response.status_code == 200:

    print("HTTP error",response.status_code)

else:

    try:

        import json

        response.content.decode('utf-8')

        response = json.dumps(response)

        loaded_response = json.loads(response)



 except:

        print("Response not in valid JSON format")

except:

print("Something went wrong with requests.get")

print(type(response))
```

Comment: Hey @Lucas_87, can you let us know if the answer helped you out?

Answer (score 0):

`Response not in valid JSON format` means that your response data is not in a valid JSON format.

It's not very clear what you want, but the URL you are requesting `https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Strona_g%C5%82%C3%B3wna` does not return JSON formatted data, it returns a full html document (try opening the URL in your browser).
Therefore you cannot convert it to a JSON object.

JSON formatted data would look something like:

`{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`

If you would like to test your code you can use a URL from a placeholder service, i.e. `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`

A (GET) request to this URL will return JSON formatted placeholder data so you can test and experiment with your code.

You can learn more about JSON here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Good luck!